# Burn Sqlite database to app

Tags: android, sqlite

I know how to use a Sqlite database with my app. But here is my doubt. I have inserted all the needed data using Sqlite manager and have created a DB. Now is it possible for me to push this DB into my app so that each and every-time I don't have to insert data into this db and also will I be able to have these data inside the db when the app is being installed on other devices?

Comment: Check [this](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) out!

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good sqllite tutorial on android on this site. 
[Vogella: Android SQLite](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

yes. you can ship a database with the app. its just another file isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Import it in the folder

```
/data/data/yourPackage
DB_PATH="/data/data/yourPackage"

DataService dataService = new DataService(this, DB_NAME, DB_PATH,DB_VERSION);
```

Enjoy... :P